# PHP - How to count 60 days from the add date

Tags: php, datetime

Let me know :)

```
$add_date = date ("Y-m-d H:m:s"); 
$expiry_date = 'how?';
```

How to insert into db the `$expiry_date` for 60 days. mysql format is datetime

Comment: Was this voted down just because it's a simple question?  Let's be a little forgiving, people :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime("+60 days"));
```

or more simply:

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', time() + 86400 * 60);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP >= 5.2 I strongly suggest you use the new DateTime object. For example like below:

```
$add_date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s"); 
$expiry_date = new DateTime($add_date);
$expiry_date ->modify("+60 days");
echo $expiry_date ->format("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecbac018080a44749f267b070fddea28682372d8)

Answer (score 2):

A method avoiding time conversions:

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', time()+3600*24*60)
```

**EDIT**
However, it may be less readable and the time saved is probably irrelevant. Plus cletus just edited a similar method into his answer