# PHP Calculating future date by adding days to a variable date

Tags: php, math, date

I was looking at this post, and it is close to what I need: 
[PHP - How to count 60 days from the add date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669165/php-how-to-count-60-days-from-the-add-date)

However, in that post, the calculation is performed by adding 60 days to the current date. What I need to do is calculate the date based on a variable date (*and not the current date*).

Something like this:

```
$my_date = $some_row_from_a_database;
$date_plus_10_days = ???;
```

Anyone know how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What's the date format in the database (timestamp)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can put something before the "+10 days" part:

```
strtotime("2010-01-01 +10 days");
```

Comment: +1 learnt a new thing today. Thanks. Probably the OP wants to convert back to some human readable string. So, something like date('Y-m-d',strtotime("2010-01-01 +10 days"));

Comment: `strototime` takes a timestamp as the second argument which will be used as the reference timestamp for what you put as first argument, so if the OP got a timestamp from the MySQL, he can just as well do `strtotime('+60 days', $timestampFromMySql);`

Answer (score 6):

Use date_add

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

```
$my_date = new DateTime($some_row_from_a_database);
$date_plus_10_days = date_add($my_date, new DateInterval('P10D'));
```

Comment: You should mention that this  is  only available from PHP 5.3.0 on.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to look into [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). I'd imagine your final code would look something like this:

```
$dateVariable      = strtotime('2017-01-29');//your date variable goes here
$date_plus_60_days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 60 days', $dateVariable));
echo $date_plus_60_days;
```

If you are using PHP >= 5.2 I strongly suggest you use the new DateTime object. For example like below:

```
$date_plus_60_days = new DateTime("2006-12-12");
$date_plus_60_days->modify("+60 days");
echo $date_plus_60_days->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are retriving data from a database.
If you are using mysql you can do it on the select:

Example: you need the last date of the table and this date-7 days

```
select max(datefield) as ultimaf, DATE_SUB(max(datefield),INTERVAL 7 DAY) as last7
from table
```

It´s easy use curdate() if you want todays date.

If you need a dynamic between that selects the count of last 7 days:

```
select count(*) from table
where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)<=datefield"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2014-11-24 06:33:39" +35 days"))
```

this will get the calculated date in defined format.

Answer (score 1):

*Suppose today's date is*

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$today=date("Y-m-d");
```

*And i can add 10 days in current date as follows :*

```
$date_afte_10_days = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$today +10 days"));
```