# Adding days to $Date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date returned as part of a MySQL query in the form `2010-09-17`.

I would like to set the variables $Date2 to $Date5 as follows:

`$Date2 = $Date + 1`

`$Date3 = $Date + 2`

etc., so that it returns `2010-09-18`, `2010-09-19`, etc.

I have tried

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 day'))
```

but this gives me the date *before* `$Date`.

What is the correct way to get my Dates in the format form 'Y-m-d' so that they may be used in another query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Calculating future date by adding days to a variable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692679/php-calculating-future-date-by-adding-days-to-a-variable-date)

Answer (score 566, accepted):

All you have to do is use `days` instead of `day` like this:

```
<?php
$Date = "2010-09-17";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 days'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 2 days'));
?>
```

And it outputs correctly:

```
2010-09-18
2010-09-19
```

Comment: It outputs correctly using just `day` as well... `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2010-09-17 + 1 day'))` -> `2010-09-18`, `date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2010-09-17 + 2 day'))` -> `2010-09-19`

Comment: Just tried it this way and it worked. I still have no idea why I got a value one day before my start date when I initially tried it.

Comment: What if I had a variable for de number of days to add?

Comment: @Carlos echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Date.' + '.$variable.' days'));

Comment: Nope this method doesn't works at all. It is returning some date of 2004.

Answer (score 111):

If you're using PHP 5.3, you can use a [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and its [`add`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method:

```
$Date1 = '2010-09-17';
$date = new DateTime($Date1);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // P1D means a period of 1 day
$Date2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Take a look at the [`DateInterval` constructor](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) manual page to see how to construct other periods to add to your date (2 days would be `'P2D'`, 3 would be `'P3D'`, and so on).

Without PHP 5.3, you should be able to use `strtotime` the way you did it (I've tested it and it works in both 5.1.6 and 5.2.10):

```
$Date1 = '2010-09-17';
$Date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date1 . " + 1 day"));
// var_dump($Date2) returns "2010-09-18"
```

Comment: Sorry Daniel, but the webserver runs php 5.2.6, so this won't work

Comment: `DateTime::construct` uses the same mechanism as `strtotime` to parse the date, so you can also do `new DateTime("+1 day $date")` which would not require 5.3

Comment: This is the actual answer for php 5.5+

Comment: @Steven ► https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294938/how-can-i-undo-my-vote

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez - Heh yea I tried that but apparently my vote is locked unless this answer is edited (according to SO)

Answer (score 40):

From PHP 5.2 on you can use modify with a DateTime object:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
$Date1 = '2010-09-17';
$date = new DateTime($Date1);
$date->modify('+1 day');
$Date2 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Be careful when adding months... (and to a lesser extent, years)

Comment: accepted answer just gives answer for 15000+ days where this answer gives answer when you add 25000+ days too..

Comment: You can also query this on a DateTimeImmutable() and you get a modified copy without risk of altering the original.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a small snippet to demonstrate the date modifications:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
//increment 2 days
$mod_date = strtotime($date."+ 2 days");
echo date("Y-m-d",$mod_date) . "\n";

//decrement 2 days
$mod_date = strtotime($date."- 2 days");
echo date("Y-m-d",$mod_date) . "\n";

//increment 1 month
$mod_date = strtotime($date."+ 1 months");
echo date("Y-m-d",$mod_date) . "\n";

//increment 1 year
$mod_date = strtotime($date."+ 1 years");
echo date("Y-m-d",$mod_date) . "\n";
```

Comment: can you please see my related (quesiton)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/61421783/8919244]?

Answer (score 11):

Here has an easy way to solve this.

```
<?php
   $date = "2015-11-17";
   echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 5 days'));
?>
```

Output will be:

```
2015-11-22
```

Solution has found from here - [How to Add Days to Date in PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/add-days-to-date-in-php/)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the following format

```
strtotime("-3 days", time());
strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date));
```

You can stack changes this way:

```
strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($date)));
```

Note the difference between this approach and the one in other answers: instead of concatenating the values `+1 day` and `<timestamp>`, you can just pass in the timestamp as the second parameter of `strtotime`.

Answer (score 9):

Using a variable for Number of days

```
$myDate = "2014-01-16";
$nDays = 16;
$newDate = strtotime($myDate . '+ '.$nDays.' days');
echo new Date('d/m/Y', $newDate); //format new date
```

Comment: What is "`$soma`"? Some weird typo of "`$newDate`"?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simplest solution to your query

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15"); // or your date string
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));// add number of days 
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d"); //set date format of the result
```

Answer (score 2):

> This works. You can use it for days, months, seconds and reformat the date as you require

```
public function reformatDate($date, $difference_str, $return_format)
{
    return date($return_format, strtotime($date. ' ' . $difference_str));
}
```

> Examples

```
echo $this->reformatDate('2021-10-8', '+ 15 minutes', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $this->reformatDate('2021-10-8', '+ 1 hour', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $this->reformatDate('2021-10-8', '+ 1 day', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a certain number of days to a date, use the following function.

```
function add_days_to_date($date1,$number_of_days){
    /*
    //$date1 is a string representing a date such as '2021-04-17 14:34:05'
    //$date1 =date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    // function date without a secrod argument returns the current datetime as a string in the specified format
    */
    $str =' + '. $number_of_days. ' days';
    $date2= date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date1. $str));
    return $date2; //$date2 is a string
}//[end function]
```

Answer (score 0):

All have to use bellow code:

```
$nday = time() + ( 24 * 60 * 60);    
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";    
echo 'Next Day: '. date('Y-m-d', $nday) ."\n";
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way, eventually you will have problems with leap seconds

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert your date string into a timestamp and then add the appropriate number of seconds to it.

```
$datetime_string = '2022-05-12 12:56:45';
$days_to_add = 1;
$new_timestamp = strtotime($datetime_string) + ($days_to_add * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

After which, you can use one of PHP's various date functions to turn the timestamp into a date object or format it into a human-readable string.

```
$new_datetime_string = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $new_timestamp);
```

Answer (score -2):

We can implement simply add or subtract days in the current date in php

```
date('Y-m-d' , strtotime('-90days'));
```

Comment: OP says: "_I have a date returned as part of a MySQL query in the form 2010-09-17._" and they want to add days to that date.  Please only answer the asked question.