# How do i recognize a date in a string, and return it with 48 hours added?

Tags: php, string, date, addition

I've got a var $date_ordered that gives me the following string: 
"2013-07-02 07:48:06"
I want php to recognize this as a date, put it in the following format:
"2013-07-02T07:48:06+0100"
And add 48 hours to it.

How would I go about doing that?

Kind regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date to time, add 48 hours then convert to ISO 8601 (as it seems that's what you want):

```
$a = '2013-07-02 07:48:06';
$time = strtotime($a);
$time += 48 * 60 * 60;
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, $time) . PHP_EOL;
```