# PHP strtotime error when convert some date string to datetime value

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a trouble with strtotime in php.

```
$j = "2013-10-27";
for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {
  $j = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($j) + 86400);
  echo ' '.$j.' <br/>';
}
```

As the code is self explained, it will add one day to $j and then display to browser.
But when $j = "2013-10-27", it prints just one result ("2013-10-27"). If I change $j to another date, this does work, but also stucks at this date (and some other date).

I have written other code to do this work. 
But does anyone know why it fails, or my code is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: your code showing one result 100 times.where did you use $i ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce - http://codepad.viper-7.com/8wAdrh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Comment: Well, I don't use $i, but $x just for counting (in this code).

Comment: I have tested on PHP 5.4.19, PHP 5.3.1 (with XAMPP on Windows 8), and got the same result. So I decide to ask you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are in a timezone with daylight savings time, and on the 27th October at 1 AM the time reverted to midnight, making it a 25 hour day.

This can be reproduced by setting the timezone:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$j = "2013-10-27";
for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {
  $j = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($j) + 86400);
  echo ' '.$j.' <br/>';
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/uTbNWf

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime` has [too many limitations](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) in my opinion. Use the more recent `DateTime` lib instead

```
$j = new DateTime('2013-10-27');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {
    $j->add($interval);
    echo $j->format('Y-m-d'), '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Consequentially, this takes care of the DST switch mentioned in [Paul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19721032/283366)