# HOw to add specific noumber of days to date stored in a variable

Tags: php, date, addition, days

I am fetching date from database and stored it in a variable called `$lastRequest[1]`. Now I need to add certain number of days which are stored in variable `$licChkFreq` to the date stored in `$lastRequest[1]`.

I am using this code:

```
$nextRequest=$newExp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($lastRequest[1])) . " +".$licChkFreq." day");
$nextRequest=date("Y-m-d",$nextRequest);
```

Comment: So if i understood you correctly, you want to add dates, is that right?

Comment: Use days instead of day.

Answered here already.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php

Comment: increment previous date by a certain number of days

Comment: changed day to days did not make any difference

Comment: if i have the following values $lastRequest[1]=2013-12-11 , $licChkFreq=7 I get following nextRequest=601200 and 2nd time nextRequest=1970-01-08 though it should be 2013-12-18

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this should give you what you need.

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($lastRequest[1] . " +" . $licChkFreq ." days"));
```

This is the code I tested with

```
$lastRequest[1] = '2013-12-11';
$licChkFreq = 7;

$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($lastRequest[1] . " +" . $licChkFreq ." days"));

echo $newDate;
```

Comment: still getting previous date 1970-01-01

Comment: while if i run only this code it gives correct output.          <?php
$Date = "2010-09-17";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 1 days'));
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 2 days'));
?>

Comment: Please see my update and test the code I tried with also. If the above works but when using the actual variables it doesn't, then there must be something with those variables that is causing an issue. I would maybe check each variable one by one, ie take my code and feed the `$lastRequest[1]` in first, then the `$licChkFreq`. I would also try `echo date('Y-m-d');` to see what date your server says it is. But can guarantee this is working for me.

Comment: The code given by you works if i explicitly define the  of $lastRequest[1] and $licChkFreq but if i fetch the values from database it does not work. But i checked that it fetches correct values from database by echoing them on screen.

Comment: I added trim function while fetching values from database and it worked. Maybe it was also fetching whitespace from the database along with the value.

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that was going on, glad you got it working.