# php function to add number of days to a date

Tags: php

I have found several posts regarding this topic but I cannot get my function to work.
If the amount of days to add `> 0`, the returning date = `70-01-01`

Example:
    $date='12-07-11'
    $days='5'

Should return `17-07-11` instead of `70-01-01`
I need to use the variables because $date and $days are results from an oracle query.

```
function addDayswithdate($date,$days)
{
  $originalDate = $date;
  $newDate = date("y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));

  if ($days>0)
  {
    $var="+". $days ." days";
    $date = strtotime($var, strtotime($newDate));
  }

  $originalDate = $date;
  $newDate = date("y-m-d", strtotime($date));

  return $newDate;
}
```

Comment: Try following the advice [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php).

Comment: I suggest you avoid handling dates as strings. In PHP you have timestamps and objects to choose from.

Comment: I have tried all the other posts, but the trick is in the date format, which is d-m-y

Comment: Split your task in two parts (1.- convert from string to date 2.- add one day) and solve them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Datetime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y','12-07-11');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
echo $date->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to this and it is working! $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$_date);
 $date->add(new DateInterval('P'. $days . 'D'));
 return $date->format('d-m-Y') . "\n";

Comment: Now this is the answer I was looking for. I have got date saved as string but every other answer on similar questions on stack overflow assumes that date is in date format! There are many such questions and your answer should definitely come at the top of all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simpler?

```
function addDays($date, $days)
{
   $time = strtotime($date);
   $new_time = $time + (86400 * $days) //86400 seconds per day
   return $new_time;
}
```

Comment: Because some days have 23 or 25 hours (apart from leap seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date + $days .'days'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDays($date, $days)
{
    $date_uts = strtotoime($date);
    $add_days = $days*86400;

    $final_date = date('Y-m-d', $date_uts+$add_days);
    return $final_date;
}
```

Comment: If $date = 23-06-11 and $days = 1, the returning value is 2023-06-12. Not correc. Should be 24-06-11

Comment: Assuming that days always have 86400 seconds is like assuming months always have 30 days, except that the error is harder to spot. Don't get into this path: date calculations are hard, let the computer do them for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition of using vanilla php DateTime class, you can use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) if you have to work often with dates.

Carbon let you do anything like this

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addDays(5);
```