# How to modify a date/time variable in PHP

Tags: php

I am receiving the variable `$CheckIn`
`$CheckIn` is  a date in Y-m-d format, how can i create a `$Checkout` variable with the value +8 days after checkin.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Show your code to us

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$checkout = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($checkin. ' + 8 days'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$Date = "2010-09-17";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + 8 days'));//save this in any variable
```

Answer (score 0):

With `DateTime()`

```
$date = new DateTime($checkin);
$date->modify('+8 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```