# How to get date when given a date and days from that date? php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have to get a date in the future.

I have a date in the past and I need to add "X" days and get the resulting date.

Here is an example of what I want to do

2016-02-28 09:07:22 + 62 days = NewDate

I am using PHP

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert the date string into seconds, then add the days, and then convert back with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function if you want. The code will look like this:

```
$dateString = '2016-02-28 09:07:22';
$time = strtotime($dateString); //convert to seconds
$timeNew = $time + 62 * 24 * 60 * 60; //add 62 days in seconds
$dateNew = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timeNew); //convert back
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `\DateTime()` object, you can do something like:

```
$past = new \DateTime('2016-02-28 09:07:22');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P64D'); // 64 days
$future = $past->add($interval);
```