# How to select rows with Laravel and MySQL depending on a datetime field and an interval field

Tags: mysql, laravel

I would like to select records from a MySQL table with Laravel where NOW() is later than a datetime-field plus the value of an integer-field (seconds). - How can I do this?

Table "records"

- id (int)
- name (varchar)
- updated_at (datetime)
- update_interval (int)

I wish to accomplish something like:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE NOW() > (updated_at + update_interval);
```

And then written as a Laravel where-condition like:

```
Record::where( 'NOW()', '>', 'created_at + update_interval' );
```

Comment: I bet update_interval is days? Then, checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php

Comment: And you have to make sure to compare on same format

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to compute a time. Adding a number to a `DATETIME` column reduces it to a numerical value.

Instead use `DATE_ADD` to keep it as the proper type:

```
Record::where('NOW()', '>', 'DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL update_interval SECOND)')
```

You can adjust the interval computation here by using different units. Seconds offer the most control, but lead to large, confusing to read numbers like 86400.