# How to set a date of n number of days ago in php

Tags: php, date

I have a php variable:

```
$datevar = date("Y-m-d");
```

Which shows me the CURRENT date in the specified format.

What I want is the date from 7 days ago for CURRENT date in that format. 
I have tried:

```
$datevar = $datevar - 7;
```

and

```
$datevar = date("Y-m-d") - 7 ;
```

But they both cause an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727821/7454754

So in your example this would be something like

```
<?php
  $today = date("Y-m-d");
  $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($today . " - 7 days"));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel! you have a nice day buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below, that should work:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date 
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " -1 week");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. Here we are using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

[**Try this code snippet here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a44082da0a52c6e87f614fe6bac7c8792d8ff3b)

```
<?php

$datevar = date("Y-m-d");//your date

$dateTimeObj=new DateTime($datevar);
$dateTimeObj->sub(new DateInterval("P7D"));//subtracting 7 days
echo $dateTimeObj->format("Y-m-d");
```