# Finding date expire (enddate) php

Tags: php

I got this code from script.php this code for enddate but this code display number days and me im search for displays date end

exmple:
code display 30 days expire

and me im search display 18/02/2018 expire

```
public function days($enddate)
{
    $now = time();
    $your_date = strtotime($enddate);
    $datediff = $your_date - $now;
    $rem = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
    return ($rem <= 0 ? 0 : $rem);
}
```

Comment: Can you include a example call to the function and include the actual and expected results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use the `date` method to format your timestamp as following:

```
public function days($enddate) {
    $now = time();
    $diff = strtotime($enddate) - $now;
    return date('d/m/Y', $now + $diff);
}
```

Comment: Code expires after: 30\/01\/1970 (incorrect) - normally display Code expires after: 18/02/2017