# PHP add date based in user selection

Tags: php

I want to add 'x' number of days to current date. The days will be select by user and add to current date.
Below is my select days code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Date</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form name=date method="post" action="test.php">
            <table style="width: 60%;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><h3>Date</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. of Days</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="days" style="width: 270px">
                            <option value ="Select">Select</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value ="14">14</option>
                            <option value ="21">21</option>
                            <option value ="28">28</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Submit'></td>
                    <td><input type='reset' value='Reset'></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
</body>
```

Below is the code after submit

```
<?php
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$days = $_POST["days"];
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' + '. $_POST["days"]));
?>
```

But the results will always show as "1970-01-01"

Hope to get some tips. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Comment: You might get away changing the `value` in your `option`s to ready for example `"7 days"` instead of just `"7"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There something wrong with your code within `strtotime()` function try any of these to get the same result as you want...

**By `strtotime()`:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' + '.$_POST["days"].' days')); 
// This can be also written as strtotime('+'.$_POST['days'].' days '.$Date);
```

**By `modify()`:**

```
$date = new DateTime($Date);
$date->modify('+'.$_POST["days"].' day');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("40 days"));
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```