# mysql how to get max value for a certain day?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which holds sensor data:

> id, name(varchar), value(float), time(datetime)

Now i need to select the **max value of a certain day**.

I'm getting a **variable number like "1"** which means, it should be the highest value of yesterday.

So how can i use this number to get the max value of this day?

I know so far there is this construct:

```
subdate(CURDATE(), ".$day.")
```

And also got a query for max value:

```
SELECT MAX(value) AS value FROM ".$tablename." WHERE sensor_id=? AND value_id=?
```

But i have problems to combine this with the date...

Hopefully you can help. thx

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `AND \`time\` = '2018-05-01 10:00:00'` or `AND DATE(\`time\`) = '2018-05-01'`

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result as the columns in the table and those in the query you provided are not coherent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information in your question (and using your variable names), I think this query will work for you:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(value) AS value 
          FROM " . $tablename . "
          WHERE sensor_id=? AND
                value_id=? AND 
                DATE(time)=SUBDATE(CURDATE()," . $days . ")";
```

Comment: thx exactly what i looked for. Exactly this part i missed in my query: DATE(time)=.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable holding yesterday is $date_less and $datetime is the variable holding currnet date then your code look like this

```
$datetime   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date_less  = 1;
"SELECT MAX(value) AS value FROM ".$tablename." WHERE sensor_id=? AND value_id=? and `time` = ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($datetime.' -'.$date_less.' days'));
```

for more information on adding days in date you can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)