# php Adding dynamic days in dynamic date is not working

Tags: php

I have code given below:

```
       $split=explode(' ',$getdate);
       $date=$split['0'];                                   //comming 2018-06-04
        $newdates = date ($date, strtotime ("+".$days) ) ;  //days having 30 value
      // $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdates );         
       $currentdate=date('Y-m-d');
       echo "<pre>";print_r($newdates);
```

but its not adding the 30 days in the current date can anyone please help me related this

Comment: Where are $getdate & $days coming from.  What are you actually trying to output?

Comment: $split['0'] I think should be $split[0], right?

Comment: every thing is working fine but ists not adding the days thats it / after split i am getting the date in Y-m-d

Comment: you're using `date()` wrong, here's the line problem `$newdates = date ($date, strtotime ("+".$days) ) ;`, you already know you need to provide the format on the first argument

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Comment: just use `DateTime` object, then use `$date = new DateTime($split[0]);
echo $date->modify('+' . $days . ' days')->format('Y-m-d');` like so, no fuzz or anything else

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like

```
 $newdates = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ($date . " + " . $days . "days") )
```

or simply

```
 $newdates = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ("+ " . $days . "days") )
```

Comment: after your first step i am gettin all date like 1970-01-01 ... not adding the days

Comment: $newdates = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ($date . " + 30days"));
 if i used this its working

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to build an array containing the next 30 days, loop over the date() & strtotime() functions like so:

```
$todaysDate = date('Y-m-d');
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++){

  $newDates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todaysDate .  ' +' . $i . ' days'));

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newDates);
```