# Add number of days to datetime and then find difference in days between two dates

Tags: php

I have saved a date in mysql table in **date('Y-m-d H:i:s')** format

```
$blacklisted_date = "2018-07-22 17:57:24";
$blacklisted_days = 7;
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I want to add **$blacklisted_days** to **$blacklisted_date**

```
$result_date = $blacklisted_date + $blacklisted_days;
```

and then want to find the difference in days between the **$result_date** and **$now**.

```
$diff_days = $result_date - $now;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using DateTime class, look here:

```
$blacklisted_date = "2018-07-22 17:57:24";
$blacklisted_days = 7;

$date1 = new DateTime($blacklisted_date); // blacklisted
$date1->add(new DateInterval("P{$blacklisted_days}D")); // add N days

$date2 = new DateTime(); // now
$interval = $date1->diff($date2); // get diff
echo $interval->days; // in days
```

I hope it's really clear to understand

Comment: Thank you @MrSmile, if `$blacklisted_date = "2018-07-22 00:00:00";` and `$date2 = new DateTime("2018-07-22 00:00:01");` because of this one second difference the result is `6`, I want if whole day passes the difference should be `6`.

Comment: @DMP, you can do some condition using other info from `$interval` array like hours. For example `if $interval->hours >= 22) { $total_days = $interval->days+1; }` or similar you want. check `print_r($interval)` and you'll get more useful data

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code block will help you solve the problem.

```
    $blacklisted_date = "2018-07-22 17:57:24";
    $blacklisted_days = 7;
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $result_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($blacklisted_date . '+'. $blacklisted_days.' days'));

    if( $result_date > $now ){
       $datediff = strtotime($result_date) - strtotime($now);  
    }else{
       $datediff = strtotime($now) - strtotime($result_date);
    }

    $diff_days = round( $datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```