# Cant get dates in a correct way

Tags: php, date

i cant get this to work.
I want to enter a date in d/m/Y and add it days and get the result in d/m/y too but apparently php takes the original input of the date as m/d/Y anyways

```
<?php

$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/04/2018')- 
>format('d/m/Y');
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ymd. ' + 5 days'));
```

The output is 09/01/2018 but it is actually taking the 04 in the date input as days when it is the month.
The result should be 06/04/2018. 
How can i get this to work? I tried everything.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `strtotime()` sees `01/04/2018` as month/day/year as when it sees slahes (`/`) it assumes US format. What `Datetime()` is doing is irrelevant here as it already has executed and created a date string for you. You need to convert that date into a format that `strtotime()` recognizes as a European date if you want it to add days correctly.

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/04/2018')->format('m/d/Y');
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($ymd. ' + 5 days'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MRtVa)

Additionally, I don't know why you are using both `DateTime()` and `strtotime()` when `DateTime()` already can do everything you need:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/04/2018')->modify('+5 days')->format('d/m/Y');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PoOrP)