# facing non well formed numeric error in php

Tags: php

I am trying find the next date.Suppose today is 23-07-2019 and i want to echo 24-07-2019 but i can't. I execute the below code and it gives me some error.
they give this error :

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\telehealth\twilio_Sms\autometic.php on line 2 
>       24

Now please anyone help what is my mistake and what should i change to correct this. I am trying many thins but i could not solve it

```
echo (date('d-m-Y')+"1");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Comment: Try this : echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime(' +1 day'));

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that the `date('d-m-Y')` returns string with `-` symbols and you try to sum it with a `"1"`. You can't mix php types in this way.

First of all you definitely should read about [php types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php), [php math operations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and [type juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Next, there is a special [library to work with date and time](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). And you definitely should use it to date and time operations. The `DateTime` is an object that contents date and time and can be represented as string by [`format` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Operations with date and time are quite difficult (leap years, February and so son). And it is highly recommended to use special API from `DateTime`.

So, for you task (refer to [`add` function of datetime](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)):

```
$date = new \DateTime('23-07-2019');
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d);
```