# PHP Get date from uptime

Tags: php, date, datetime

i want ask php,

Date now is : `10:10:10 18/08/2020`

Router Uptime is : `1w1d11h1m1s`

when is date of turning on the Router? example `10:10:10 11/08/2020`

Need function php with format date `H:i:s d/m/Y`

New EDIT
add example function:

```
$uptime = "1w1d11h1m1s";

function turn_on($uptime)
{
$w = str_replace('w', ' weekdays', $uptime);
$d = str_replace('d', ' days', $uptime);
$h = str_replace('h', ' hours', $uptime);
$i = str_replace('m', ' minutes', $uptime);
$s = str_replace('s', ' seconds', $uptime);

echo 'date is' . ('H:i:s d/m/Y' ,strtotime(' - '. $w $d $h $i $s ));
}
```

Thanks for everybody who can help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Comment: not same sir, my input format XwXdXhXmXs to output H:i:s d/m/Y

Comment: There isn't a builin function to parse your router's interval format, you'll need to roll your own. For that, you'll possibly need to gather some information about the format—at least something more than one example.

Comment: EDIT add example function, router just example device sir. hiks now vote -3

Comment: Your function doesn't look bad but we don't really know much about the format. Are the tokens shown mandatory? Can there be additional ones such as months or years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you can get $uptime reformatted, you would need to split it first then convert it to a timestamp and output it as you prefer:-

```
public function turn_on($uptime)
{    
    $items = preg_split('/[^0-9]/i', $uptime);
 
    $timeStamp =  strtotime("- $items[0] week 
                             $items[1] days 
                             $items[2] hours 
                             $items[3] minutes 
                             $items[4] seconds");

    return date('H:i:s d/m/Y', $timeStamp);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to allow for - as requested