# How do I iterate between two dates in php?

Tags: php

I want to iterate between two dates in `php`. This is my code:

```
for($y=date("01/01/2017");$y<=date("01/06/2017");$y++){
    echo $y . "<br>";
}
```

Expected output:

```
01/01/2017
02/01/2017
03/01/2017
04/01/2017
05/01/2017
06/01/2017...... like this till 01/06/2017
```

Actual output:

```
01/01/2017
01/01/2018
01/01/2019
01/01/2020
01/01/2021
01/01/2022....
```

How do I get the correct dates?

**EDIT:** The dates should be in *dd/mm/yyyy* format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", '01-01-2017');
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", '01-06-2017');

while ($date <= $endDate) {
    echo $date->format("d/m/Y") . "\n";
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```

I tested this at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/461ae543a882cf8d5e933a4ddc27e8e907f74e01

Comment: That doesn't return OP's "_Expected output_" but the "_Actual output_" though. Might want to change `+ 1 year` to `+ 1 day`

Comment: How's that look?