# How to calculate month deadline in php

Tags: php, html, datetime, monthcalendar, deadline-timer

I'm working on a system that allow the user to set the number of month for their own duration as the deadline for their project. The problem I'm facing now is how do I calculate their duration starting from the day they submitted their project to its deadline.

This is the input where the user can set their month duration:

```
<label>Duration:</label>
<input type="number" name="duration" placeholder="Number of months" required="">
```

This is what I wanted to do just to make it clear:

*Let's say the user set 9 month on duration input.

*And since today is september 2021 as I posted this problem. The start of the project will be this month, and the deadline will be on 2022 June.

I already searched something about this and I can't find the right solution or maybe I just don't know the right keyword to search for.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You don't have to calculate the duration, they're giving it to you.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Sorry for my english, i already edited my question. Thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding days to $Date in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727615/adding-days-to-date-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correclty you want to add X month to the current date.

You can do something like

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('+'. $x . ' month'); //x is your input value
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php for more information.

Comment: Thankyou! you have understand my logic, but your code is having error on me, I just removed the dot ( . ) inside and it worked.

Comment: The code propably didn't worked because there was a '+' sign after the 2nd dot which shouldn't be there. I changed it in my answer. You should use dots for concatenation.