# mysql & php: adding time or day to the created/ updated time in the database

Tags: php, mysql, time

This is the time formate I store in my mysql database for each item of a data injection, for instance,

```
2010-12-04 16:00:09
```

I will output the time like this

```
echo $item['item_updated'];
```

but I want to add 24 hours or 48 hours or maybe a week of hours to this time output - how can I do that?

the result will be like, for instance,

```
2010-12-05 10:00:09 // due to 2010-12-04 16:00:09 + 24 hours
```

thanks.

Comment: Please give example of exactly how you want the result to look.

Comment: +24 hours does not return `2010-12-05 10:00:09`, typo?

Comment: yes +24 does not return the timedate that I am after that's why I posted this thread to ask how to do that. now i use PHP DateTime Object so it solves my issue. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Calculating future date by adding days to a variable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692679/php-calculating-future-date-by-adding-days-to-a-variable-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using PHP DateTime Object and it's relevant [member method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).