# PHP Countdown like Amazon Delivery

Tags: php, javascript, timer, countdown

I have been wondering this for a while and has searched for an answer over the internet but still no luck.

**My question is:** How do I create a timer be it in Javascript or PHP like the one amazon uses to tell you how long you have left to order for a specified delivery time.

[Example:](http://www.amazon.co.uk/WATT-PEARL-LIGHT-BULB-BAYONET/dp/B002B8NWTK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1368289606&sr=8-1&keywords=light%20bulbs) 
I am talking about the text that displays: 
**Want delivery by Monday, 13 May? Order it in the next 18 hours and 29 minutes.**

I hope I have made some sense. If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: And looked to the right ----->

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Countdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532553/javascript-countdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this points you in the right direction:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

[PHP Calculating future date by adding days to a variable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692679/php-calculating-future-date-by-adding-days-to-a-variable-date)

[Javascript Countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532553/javascript-countdown)

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me out!